# How to link HTML CSS and PHP together?

Tags: php, html, css, netbeans

I created a new PHP project using Netbeans and i have some trouble referencing the very same css file to all my links in the project.

This is what I have:
[image]

If you know why this is happening please let me know.

Comment: Please delete the image, and share code instead.  Posting screenshots of code is terrible because it's so small nobody can read it, and also it means we can't copy paste your code to run on our computers, so it's super hard to help you by testing and debugging locally.  Also, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a path problem

In register.php you should use `../css/style.css` because register.php is in a subdirectory (links), index.php is in root path, then you can use `css/style.css`

Comment: Thanks it works great now. is there a default directory scheme that everyone uses? should I follow a different way of doing this?

Comment: @LoizosVasileiou The scheme you used is fine. Just remember that using a relative path, it must match your structure.

Comment: okay great. thanks again for your help @Andrea Manzi